# use highmaps in .vue file

Tags: vue.js, highcharts

i need to create a .vue page with highcharts map, i would like to insert the italian map following this example:

https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/mapdata/countries/it/it-all
i still don't understand how import this script and so the reference to the italian map:

here is some code about what i'm trying:

```
<template>
    <div id="Cdl">
        <div class="main-wrapper">
            <Highmaps :options="options" />
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>

    import HighCharts from 'vue-highcharts';
    import loadMap from 'highcharts/modules/map.js';
    import { genComponent } from 'vue-highcharts';
    export default {
        components: {
            Highmaps: genComponent('Highmaps', HighCharts),
        },
        data() {
            return {
                options:{
                    chart: {
                        map: 'countries/it/it-all'
                    },
                    title: {
                        text: 'Highmaps basic demo'
                    },
                    subtitle: {
                        text: 'Italy'
                    },
                    mapNavigation: {
                        enabled: true,
                        buttonOptions: {
                            verticalAlign: 'bottom'
                        }
                    },
                    colorAxis: {
                        min: 0
                    },
                    series: [{
                        data: [
                            ['it-na', 0],
                            ['it-tp', 1],
                            ['it-pa', 2],
                            ['it-me', 3],
                            ['it-ag', 4],
                            ['it-nu', 5],
                            ['it-og', 6],
                            ['it-ms', 7],
                            ['it-mt', 8],
                            ['it-bn', 9],
                            ['it-cl', 10],
                            ['it-an', 11],
                            ['it-pg', 12],
                            ['it-ci', 13],
                            ['it-ss', 14],
                            ['it-ot', 15],
                            ['it-gr', 16],
                            ['it-li', 17],
                            ['it-ar', 18],

                        ],
                        name: 'Random data',
                        states: {
                            hover: {
                                color: '#BADA55'
                            }
                        },
                        dataLabels: {
                            enabled: true,
                            format: '{point.name}'
                        }
                    }]
                },

            }

        },
        created() {

            loadMap(HighCharts)

        },
    };
</script>
```

Answer (score 4):

As you can read in [this documentation](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-vue#loading-maps):

> There are two ways of loading maps and using them with wrapper. You can install the @highcharts/map-collection` npm package with all maps included, and then import that maps which you would like to use in your project:

```js
import Highcharts from 'highcharts'
import mapData from '@highcharts/map-collection/custom/world.geo.json'

Highcharts.maps['myMapName'] = mapData
```

> If you won't install a package with all maps, there is an option to choose necessary map from Highmaps collection and copy a map data into a new file in your project. Then just import it wherever you want, and use it in the same way like above.

I prepared the demos with both ways of usage, so please refer them.

https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-vue-demo-mqxde (with copying appropriate map into a separate file)
https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-vue-demo-rdp7f (importing map from npm package)

Comment: hello, thanks for your answer, i'm trying to import the italian map, but  in this example: https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-vue-demo-rdp7f trying to import the italian map it shows blank map , i use import like this: import mapData from "@highcharts/map-collection/countries/it/it-all.geo.json"; the link of the json file is https://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/countries/it/it-all.geo.json

Comment: I assume, it does not work because the data which exists in the mentioned example not covers the map regions. Just need to set the `allAreas` equal to `true`, then you will see all regions. Here is the example: https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-vue-demo-rhj5j

Comment: i solved, i answered to my question, thanks for your support

Comment: hi, now i have another problem... if i set  `allAreas`  to  `true` the map goes over the container...is there a way to center the map?

Comment: Could you provide me with live example where the problem occurs?

Comment: i'm trying on codesandbox, but it works fine...it's my template, i use material admin vue template with vuetify.....https://github.com/tookit/vue-material-admin

Comment: Maybe you can produce some minified repository, where the problem occurs and provide me with the link?

Comment: hello, thanks again, but i cant reproduce the project, anyway i solved loading the series in the mounted() with `_this.$refs.highcharts.chart.addSeries({
states: { hover: {color: "#BADA55"}},dataLabels: {enabled: true,format: "{point.name}"},allAreas: true,data: newdata})`

Answer (score 0):

solved installing @highcharts/map-collection and creating a component Mapchart:

```
<template>
    <highcharts :constructor-type="'mapChart'" :options="options" class="map"> 
   </highcharts>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props:{
            options:Object
        }
    };
</script>
<style scoped>
    .map {
        min-height: 800px;
    }
</style>
```

then in the page whith the map i have this:

```
<template>
    <div id="app">
        <mapChart :options="mapOptions"></mapChart>
    </div>
</template>

<script>

    import Vue from "vue";

    import HighchartsVue from "highcharts-vue";
    import Highcharts from "highcharts";
    import mapInit from "highcharts/modules/map";
    import mapChart from "../../../components/mapChart";
    import mapData from "@highcharts/map-collection/countries/it/it-all.geo";

    mapInit(Highcharts);
    Highcharts.maps["myMapName"] = mapData;

    Vue.use(HighchartsVue)

    export default {
        name: "app",
        components: {
            mapChart
        }, data() {
            return {
                mapOptions: {...}
                };
            }
        };
    </script>
```

if this could help someone